# How do I call Validator from a namespace with an already existing Validator class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpspec, psr-4

I'm trying to test a function in phpspec which calls Laravel's `Validator::make` function (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation)

However, I'm trying to call that same function from a namespace where the `Validator` class name is already taken. How can I call that function described in the docs?

Failed solutions:

**Attempt 1**

```
return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator::make($values,$rules);
```

gives me

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::make()
```

**Attempt 2**

```
return \Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make($values,$rules);
```

gives me

```
Using $this when not in object context in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.php on line 92. Factory
```

**Attempt 3**

```
use \Validator;
```

gives me

```
Cannot declare class Isoform\Validator because the name is already in use
```

**Attempt 4**

```
use \Validator as DefaultValidator;
```

gives me

```
Class 'DefaultValidator' not found
```

Comment: Possible hint: "Call to undefined method" means that it did find a class at that location, but it's probably not the class you're looking for.

Comment: @mopo922 If I have the wrong class, where is the right class?

Comment: You might be able to get Laravel's validator by using `\Validator::make($values, $rules)`.

Comment: @user3158900 that returns `Class 'Validator' not found`

Comment: In Attempt 4, where does `DefaultValidator` come from? What if you also add `use \DefaultValidator` ?

Comment: Fixed. Should be more obvious now. It's basically attempt 3 but I aliased it to a different class.

Answer (score 2):

```
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($values,$rules);
```

This will cause errors in phpspec, but that cannot be avoided. Although `Validator::make` looks like a static function - behind the scenes it is really returning an instance. Because I was using phpspec, that instance was not created hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try just a single forward slash to refer to the global namespace:

```
return \Validator::make($values,$rules);
```

Comment: Thanks mopo, but its returning `Using $this when not in object context in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.php on line 92`. `Factory` has a `make` function but its not static

Comment: still nada: `Class 'Validator' not found`. Doing research into Facades, so thanks for the pointer.

Comment: That's puzzling. Are you using the "other" Validator class? If not, maybe `use \Validator;` at the top of your file would work?

Comment: That's exactly the case. My namespace has a `Validator` class, but I'm trying to access the one in the docs without renaming my current class. Both `use \Validator` and `use \Validator as DefaultValidator` still don't work (edited original question with why)

Answer (score -1):

I solved that one. Simply delete `use Validator` from `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php` and then add `use Validator` code to your controller. Then you are ready for action.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
```